# How to find out right URL to JSF page? Opening in IntelliJ IDEA causes 404

Tags: jsf, url, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm very new on Java Web dev. On intellij Idea 14, I started a new project with plain Java, JSF support (no JavaEE, will add Spring later). Tomcat 7.0.59 as server. When I hit run on the IDE, firefox opens up and hits on 'http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml', it should display the hello world in index.xhtml that the IDE makes on new project, but the page just displays 'HTTP 404'.

I think the problem is path on the browser, how can I find the correct path and configure it on IDE deploy settings?, how can I debug on tomcat?, where can I start looking?

Comment: An IDE is just like a usual text editor such as notepad but then providing thousands of extra features. It is hardly an IDE problem. Once an application is successfully deployed on a server, the server is in charge of serving  web pages and/or other resources available on the server. The server is completely unaware of any IDE, if used at all (though I am unfamiliar with the IDE you are using). Check out the `<welcome-file>` element inside `<welcome-file-list>` to see the proper listing of a welcome file which is supposed to appear on the first run of the application.

Answer (score 3):

http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml is an incomplete address. Where is the context root? It should be the name of your project/webapplication, where you would have

"http://localhost:8080/{application-name}/index.xhtml".

Unless you've set your application to be the default tomcat application (which I highly doubt), you should have the name of your project in there in the URL

Answer (score 1):

`%CATALINA_HOME%` is Tomcat install directory. Use `%CATALINA_HOME%\logs` to read Tomcat log for debugging.
When you create a new Java web project, It also means you are diving to Java EE (Enterprise Edition).
Create new JSF web application by IntelliJ IDEA:
[image]
Offical tutorial for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partwebtier.htm#BNADP .

You should use [GlassFish 4](https://glassfish.java.net/) application server for simplicity at first one.

Comment: "*You should use GlassFish 4 application server for simplicity at first one.*" Nope. GlassFish Server is now [commercially dead](http://blog.arungupta.me/glassfish-commercial-is-dead-wildfly-and-jboss-eap-to-rescue/) that should not be recommended. (Yes I still use GlassFish Server 4.1 for other reasons).

Answer (score -2):

move the lib directory into WEB-INF