# Intellij idea new project with jsf not working

Tags: jsf, tomcat, intellij-idea, http-status-code-404

Using intellij 2016, when I create a new empty JSF web application with tomcat 8 as my server, I see the 404 error message. Where should I search for the cause of this problem?

Here is a similar problem but solutions are not working:
[How to find out right URL to JSF page? Opening in IntelliJ IDEA causes 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709377/how-to-find-out-right-url-to-jsf-page-opening-in-intellij-idea-causes-404)

**Edit:**
By changing my server from tomcat to glassfish the same project is successfully deployed, so I think the problem is with tomcat but by installing a new version of tomcat, the problem remains the same for me.

Comment: Could you post your folder structure, web.xml and console log??

Comment: @BrunoDM the problem is not with my folder structure! It is generated by intellij. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

when you build the application, ".war" file will be generated to your target folder.copy that .war file to tomcat/webapps folder. Now you will be able to run your application

(home.xhtml is called as home.jsf in the url )

http://localhost:8080/WebTutorial/home.jsf

[Check this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_first_application.htm)